# jQuery animate - fade in after image has faded out?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple cloud image that I wish to go from the left to right side of the browser, where it should disappear outside the right side of the screen while fading out, and then fade back in and start the animation all over again, from the left. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var animate = function(targetElement, speed){

    $('#cloudsAnimated').css({left:'-200px'});
    $('#cloudsAnimated').animate(
        {
        'left': "100%",
        opacity:0
        },
        {
        duration: speed,
        easing:"linear",
        complete: function(){
            animate(this, speed);
            }
        }
    );

};
animate($('#cloudsAnimated'), 5000);
```

This function fades out the image as it gets to the right side of the screen, but it completely disappears and doesn't appear again (I've set the 'complete' key of the function to restart again). If I keep the opacity unchanged then it does start again, so it has something to do with the opacity. Again, I'd like the image to fade back in and start moving from left to right all over again.

Please let me know if you know a solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#cloudsAnimated").css({left: '-200px').fadeIn();
```

You may also want to use the width of `#cloudsAnimated` instead of hard coding -200

You could also use `.animate` again so that it fades in on the same queue:

```
$("#cloudsAnimated").css({left: '-200px');
$("#cloudsAnimated").animate({'left': 0, 'opacity': 1}, 500);
```

The 500 is just a guess .. if you want the real animation time it would probably be `speed` divided by the ratio of 200 to the window width.

Comment: I think that way it still won't be visible because it'll be faded out again immediately by the animate.

Comment: @Andy updated my answer; I think it will have the fadeIn effect you desire

Comment: Ah sorry i wasn't the one asking the question, just pointed it out. ;)

Comment: Great, thanks! This seems to work, but the only thing now is that I when it fades back in it has a different speed than when it faded out. What I mean, is that fades in, moves along, slows down and pretty much stops for a second, then starts moving again. I can't seem to figure out how to make it all one continuous motion.

Comment: This is because the animation duration is a lot longer for the second fade.  This is difficult to get around unless you are okay with animating it *in* for the same duration, or perhaps using a different easing function

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just changed added in the easing key and changed it from the default "swing" to "linear" in the animate() instance where the opacity is brought back to 1 and it did the trick. Appreciate the help, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset the opacity.

Try changing

```
$('#cloudsAnimated').css({left:'-200px'});
```

to

```
$('#cloudsAnimated').css({left:'-200px', opacity:1});
```

This won't fade it in though, but you should see it at least.
It also doesn't fade in the first time in your solution, does it?